# How can I get the months between two dates in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I need to get the numbers of the months between two dates.
For example, between those dates: "03/03/2020 - 06/06/2020"
I need something like "(03,04,05,06)".

Comment: `Oracle` (from question's title) or `SQL Server` (from tag info)?

Comment: From question's title, sry wrong tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Oracle:

```
SQL> column months format a24
SQL> select banner from v$version where rownum=1;

BANNER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production

SQL> select '(' || listagg(m, ',') || ')' as months
  2  from (
  3   select
  4   extract(month from to_date('03/03/2020')) m1,
  5   extract(month from to_date('06/06/2020')) m2
  6   from dual) mm
  7  inner join (
  8   select level as m
  9   from dual
 10   connect by level <= 12) l
 11  on m >= m1 and m <=m2
 12  ;

MONTHS
------------------------
(3,4,5,6)

SQL>
```

Comment: Could u explain to me why u did that, and how this work? 
"select level as m
    from dual
    connect by level <= 12) l
   on m >= m1 and m <=m2"

Comment: This is to generate a row for each month between m1 and m2 (without it I have only 3 and 6 - with it I have 3,4,5 and 6).

Answer (score 0):

Try the `DATEDIFF` function to achieve this:

```
SELECT RIGHT(CONCAT('00',DATEDIFF(MONTH,'03/06/2020','06/06/2020')) ,2)
```

Comment: Ty for ur answer and ur time trying to help me.

Answer (score 0):

I am a SQL Server programmer, and if your question was about SQL Server then the solution would be like this:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(MONTH, '2020-03-03', '2020-06-06') + 1)
Format(DateAdd(MONTH, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1, '2020-03-03'), 'MM', 
'en-US') AS MonthNumber
FROM    sys.all_objects a
)
SELECT '(' + String_Agg(MonthNumber, ', ') + ')' AS Result
FROM cte;
```

I have tested the above and it returns '(03, 04, 05, 06)' as desired.
I did my best to rewrite the above SQL Server solution into Oracle SQL, but I am unable to test it at the moment. You can try it out:

```
WITH cte AS
(
SELECT TOP (MONTHS_BETWEEN (TO_DATE('06/06/2020','DD/MM/YYYY'),
                            TO_DATE('03/03/2020','DD/MM/YYYY') ) + 1)
TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1, TO_DATE('03/03/2020','DD/MM/YYYY')), 'MM') 
AS MonthNumber
FROM sys.all_objects a
)
SELECT '(' + LIST_AGG(MonthNumber, ', ') + ')' AS Result
FROM cte;
```

Comment: Ty for ur answer and ur time trying to help me.